# Having "visible overflow" inside of a GoJS node or graphObject

Tags: javascript, gojs

I want to have a shape inside of a node, which would be partly out of the boundaries of the node. Meaning, -10px top and left of the parent element.

Right now I have rectangle and a circle inside of a node and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the link does not connect properly, since the size of the node has expanded. I would like the circle to be, using css terms, to be absolutely positioned, in other words, I don't want it to affect the node sizing the node (which is, obviously, invisible in this sample).

I have tried the following solutions:

Setting width and height to the node. Then it crops the circle, because it is out of the boundaries.

Using the fromSpot and toSpot properties in the node to connect the link to the center of the node. Apparently they are overridden by the layout, and I can't figure out how to disable isLayoutPositioned

Using adornments, but I don't understand at all how am I supposed to use them.

Searching if I could somehow set the overflow of the element visible, or to affect somehow the boundaries, or something like that, but have not found anything which would work for me.

What would be the proper solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your **Node** a "Spot" Panel, make the "main" element of your node the "port" by assigning it a **GraphObject.portId**, and position the red circle relative to the "main" element by setting its **GraphObject.alignment** property, in this case to `go.Spot.TopLeft`.  I'm also guessing that assigning the **Node.locationObjectName** is what you will want.

`myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Spot",
        { locationSpot: go.Spot.Center, locationObjectName: "BODY" },
        $(go.Shape,
          { name: "BODY", width: 50, height: 50,
            fill: "lightgreen", strokeWidth: 0,
            portId: "" }),
        $(go.Shape, "Circle",
          { alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft, width: 20, height: 20,
            fill: "transparent", stroke: "red" })
      );`

[image]

Please read more at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/nodes.html.  I recommend reading not only the Getting Started page, http://gojs.net/learn, but also all of the Introduction pages, http://gojs.net/intro, that apply to the kind of app you want to create.

In particular, these should be useful:

- http://gojs.net/latest/intro/panels.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/intro/tablePanels.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html
- http://gojs.net/latest/intro/nodes.html